# MySQL Syntax Error During UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, forms

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $Day1 = $_POST['day1'];
    $Day2 = $_POST['day2'];
    $Day3 = $_POST['day3'];
    $Day4 = $_POST['day4'];
    $Day5 = $_POST['day5'];
    $Day6 = $_POST['day6'];
    $Day7 = $_POST['day7'];
    $Day8 = $_POST['day8'];
    $Day9 = $_POST['day9'];
    $Day10 = $_POST['day10'];
    $Day11 = $_POST['day11'];
    $Day12 = $_POST['day12'];
    $Day13 = $_POST['day13'];
    $Day14 = $_POST['day14'];

    $query_update = ("UPDATE user_glucose SET (Day1='$Day1',Day2='$Day2',Day3='$Day3',Day4='$Day4',Day5='$Day5',Day6='$Day6',Day7='$Day7',Day8='$Day8',Day9='$Day9',Day10='$Day10',Day11='$Day11',Day12='$Day12',Day13='$Day13',Day14='$Day14') WHERE username='$username'");

    $result_update = mysql_query($query_update);
    echo "Data Successfully Updated !";
    echo"<p>";
    echo mysql_error();
    echo"</p>";


}
```

I am trying to update the value from a form to the table named "user_glucose".
But whenever I click on Submit this error pops up :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Day1='10',Day2='10',Day3='0',Day4='0',Day5='0',Day6='0',Day7='0',Day8='0',Day9=' at line 1

I am very new to PHP and MySQL programming and I don't know what is the problem. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need the brackets around the fields you're updating.

Comment: @andrewsi          thanks alot. That was the problem.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use parenthesis in your `UPDATE` query, simply change to

```
    $query_update = ("UPDATE user_glucose SET Day1='$Day1',Day2='$Day2',Day3='$Day3',Day4='$Day4',Day5='$Day5',Day6='$Day6',Day7='$Day7',Day8='$Day8',Day9='$Day9',Day10='$Day10',Day11='$Day11',Day12='$Day12',Day13='$Day13',Day14='$Day14' WHERE username='$username'");
```

Then I  would like to let you know that you are at risk of `sql injection`, have a look here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should use prepared statment to avoid any risk

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses around the `SET` values:

```
UPDATE user_glucose SET Day1='$Day1', ...
```

---

Your code is highly vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$query_update = "UPDATE user_glucose SET Day1='$Day1',Day2='$Day2',Day3='$Day3',Day4='$Day4',Day5='$Day5',Day6='$Day6',Day7='$Day7',Day8='$Day8',Day9='$Day9',Day10='$Day10',Day11='$Day11',Day12='$Day12',Day13='$Day13',Day14='$Day14' WHERE username='$username'";
```